# I had a trouble using gspread module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I was going to access google spreadsheet to wrote data on this using python gspread.
I used following code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('Copy of Google Merchant Center feed - Di: Produktflöde').sheet1

list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

It's sample code from https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html and I created credentials and client secret json file which required from this.

But I had a trouble and couldn't find any solution.

Error was below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bot2.py", line 16, in <module>
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gspread\__init__.py", line 38, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 51, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 545, in refresh
    self._refresh(http)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 780, in _do_refresh_request
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1957, in request
    cachekey,
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1622, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1528, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1376, in connect
    raise socket_err
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1311, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Dragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

(Sometimes, I saw this error `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond` instead of connectionreseterror.)

I tried to solve this issue from this error statement but all answers I found weren't helpful.

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Please give me any solution. Thank you for your considering.

Comment: Is this resolved? Do I need to post another question? Because I too have the same error and same question